# Module AppRegistry is not registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using native base for making app in react-native. I am new to both things. When I run the app It gives me this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
export default class Point extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name='menu' />
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title>Header</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right />
                </Header>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of my versions

[image]

and nativebase version is `"native-base": "^2.1.2"`

Comment: Share code of `index.ios.js`. Also check if any other packager is running

Comment: This has to be the question with the most repeated answer

Comment: Seeing to AppRegistry.js, there are lots of errors because typeScript support is not there. Is this the reason of the error? Have I to include support for typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using native base for my app here is link [native base](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Components)

and you can see there is no app registry like this

```
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('Point', () => Point)
```

but i have to do this to run my app

Comment: Did you just add this line in point class along with your code ?

Comment: ys @AvijitBarua

Answer (score 192):

Just kill all node process and start npm server and run application:

Step1: run command `killall -9 node`

> For windows users, run: `taskkill /im node.exe`
>
> Run `taskkill /f /im node.exe` if the process still persists.

Step2: run command `npm start --reset-cache`

Step3: run command `react-native run-ios` OR `react-native run-android`

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya I am trying to convert react-native project from expo to CLI. I did everything what you said, but still getting same problem. I tried every answer I found relative to this question. But nothing helped me.

Comment: for windows type- TASKKILL  /IM node.exe, or you can simply remove .expo folder

Comment: Not Working! on react-native version '0.68.1'.
Any Solution?

Comment: Not working for me too.

Comment: try this answer and also we should finish the proccess at the terminals

Answer (score 49):

Closing the current Metro Bundler and restarting by resetting the cache worked for me

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: Nothing happens !!

Comment: @SaeedZhiany please don't change the content of commands in answers if you're not absolutely certain it's a mistake.  In this case, it doesn't seem to be, given that almost _all_ the answers suggesting this command have it (and it's a common pattern).  You changed the meaning of the command, potentially rendering this answer useless to people who encounter it.

Answer (score 16):

Clear the cache with the following command:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 6):

You should have this at the bottom of the `index.ios.js` file
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('Point', () => Point);` 
and also import `AppRegistry` from `react-native`

Comment: Im using nativeBase <a href='https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html#Quick_Setup'> link </a> go here

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue - it was odd because I reset my repo to a time when the app was working. The issue was with my simulator (iOS).

For me the solution was to

1. kill the simulator program (quit)
2. then - close the terminal window that is opened when simulator is ran (Metro Bundler) [Image of my terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RctNC.png)

Answer (score 3):

Stop the node server running and run 'react-native run-ios' once again.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to get this error after I install a new package that has some native code that needs to be installed with it. Usually packages will say install npm module and then install native code via a pod install (ios specific) and after this my app usually throws this error.

In order to get rid of this error I delete and reinstall node_modules and pods since I am making an iOS app and then I also delete the build folder under ios. After that I run the packager with npm start -- --reset-cache and build my app again using the react-native run-ios command. This fixes the issue for me.

Comment: `error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening coreApp.xcworkspace.` This dev environment is such a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me for below version and on iOS:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

Step to resolve
Close the current running Metro Bundler
Try Re-run your Metro Bundler and check if this issue persists

Answer (score 2):

In my case, trying `npm start -- --reset-cache` and getting a bunch more errors, I deleted (uninstalled) the app from iOS and Android and `yarn ios` `yarn android` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating an entirely new react-native project after a computer restart and after the deletion/rebuild of the `npm_modules` folder, `Pods` folder, and my ios build folder did not work. (Quitting the Simulator, Quitting the Terminal app, Quitting XCode, cleaning the project folder in XCode, and running `killall -9 node`, `npm start -- reset-cahce` & `npm start -- --reset-cache` did not work, either). After installing all my packages, I copied and pasted my code from my old project to the new one. Same error. So then I started backtracking my most recent code changes, step by step. After reverting my most recent code changes, it worked. While adding new code little by little, I got an error telling me I forgot to `import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';`. I imported that, then continued adding my code that had previously led to the error (which was simply a `react-native-elements` `Button` and a `StyleSheet` `const styles`). All went well.

So, in the end, my only theory is that I had added too much code at once, and instead of telling me I forgot to `import {StyleSheet}` like it should have, it instead threw me a vague and infuriating `module AppRegistry` error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for one of these reasons:-

- Either, your app's entry file 'index.js' is corrupt due to syntax error or your React App could not load.
- Your `Metro Bundler` instance running is stale and corrupt.

### Solution

- Terminate already running `Metro Bundler` instance
- Reset Cache

  ```
  react-native start --reset-cache
  ```
- Delete `android/app/bulid` folder
- Start server again

Answer (score 1):

Just closing the metro bundler and rebuilding the app done my job.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Emülator
2. npm start -- --reset-cache
3. XCode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder
4. npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 1):

I tried  `killall -9 node` command in terminal

then again i run my project using `npm start` and it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

One single error but there might be multiple causes. Seeing a lot of diverse discussions in the community means this issue could be hard to find. Try to proceed with the following.

1. There might be a missing import.
2. There might be a missing configuration with the library you recently installed.
3. You may not receive errors in Android but in IOS. Then one of the lib configurations in IOS is missing.
4. Your cache needs to be reset if RN is upgraded.

If you still cannot find the issue with the above, remove some imports or screens from your App.js. Going with this you can find what exactly caused this error. This is how I found my issue after a day of research.

[Click to see further Github issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26687)

Answer (score 0):

Need to replace

```
.setJSMainModulePath("index") with .setJSMainModulePath("index.android")
```

Comment: Where? I got the same error after upgrade react native. Can be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

For me, restarting my computer appears to be enough to clear this issue.

It's often required after I've switched between branches, or merged branches using git.

Comment: I'm sure other solutions will work for some. For me a restart was the only solution I could find. Hardly drastic vs spending hours trying to debug. It's just one option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows and running yarn
open cmd on admin mode'
terminate and Restart the node process by typing this command.

Find the node: killall -9 node
force to kill : taskkill /f /im node.exe
Reset the cache : yarn start --reset-cache

Navigate to your project directory: cd myapp
Re-Run your App : yarn android

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't import a module in a component that I was using it in.

So, just check if you are importing the module you want to use...

Answer (score 0):

One of the libraries has not been linked.
To check, just comment out in the package.json one by one the latest libraries added.

yarn remove libraryName.

Then run the app with xcode and puf !

Answer (score 0):

If your are building a new **npm module** and this rely on some other dependencies already added in your project, you need to add those dependencies in the package.json of the npm package as peer dependency.

*package.json*

```
"peerDependencies":{
 "@org/your-dependency":">= 1.2.0"
}
```

```sh
[Tue Aug 31 2021 17:57:45.731]  ERROR    Error: Type oid already present, js engine: hermes
[Tue Aug 31 2021 17:57:45.732]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), js engine: hermes
[Tue Aug 31 2021 17:57:45.732]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), js engine: hermes
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was starting the metro bundler when there was an error in one of my styles.  I had an error in my code from last night, and then my computer did a restart overnight.  Trying to start everything up today resulted in this error along with `Invariant Violation: Invalid prop 'position' of value 'fixed' supplied to`. Fixing the `position` value resolved both errors.

Answer (score 0):

> npm start -- --reset-cache
>
> react-native run-ios

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

delete node_modules and install it again using `npm i`
then apply this command

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to all the above, it's worth to try to find and comment out the following code somewhere in you `redux` store directory:

```
.concat(composeWithDevtools)
```

It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was also suffering from the same error for windows OS. I resolved this by cleaning `gradlew`.

The steps are:

1. `cd android`
2. `gradlew clean`
3. `cd..`

Answer (score -2):

The solution is very simple just kill all the running nodes and restart your node server and rebuild your native application and it works.

For Linix:

```
killall -9 node
```

For Windows:

```
taskkill /im node.exe
```

For Android native App:

```
react-native run-android
```

For IOS native App:

```
react-native run-ios
```

Then finally,

```
npm start
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('your app name',  () => point);
```

Comment: Try to add some description with your code for future reader. What it does ? How it solve the problem ?