# React-native run-android stuck at 99% appDebug

Tags: react-native

I have previously shut down the react-native run-android still it gets stuck at 99% executing . I don't seem to find any solution to this .please help[image]

Comment: Have you try with killall node server and restart it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604603/module-appregistry-is-not-registered-callable-module-calling-runapplication/51304124#51304124

Comment: yeah finally figured it out had to shut down my PC to get it right

Answer (score 54):

Please, try this:

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

Comment: this worked for me on linux with a 0.68v react native app

Comment: Worked for me 4 years later, macos and react native 0.72.5

Answer (score 8):

In android device go to USB preference and select "File transfer" to fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

shutting down my mac after trying several commands, like the two above was the solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting current virtual device and creating new device worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Steps -

1. Go to android studio
2. Open AVD Manager
3. Wipe data for the emulator
4. Run = `npx react-native run-android` again

Answer (score 1):

sudo lsof -i:8081 , 
kill -9 pid .

Answer (score 0):

I tried with **npm run android --stacktrace** and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reason may be that Android has pending emulator update.

Answer (score 0):

1-Run "gradlew clean" command under android folder.

For example :  C:\workspace\myProject\android\gradlew clean

2-Then It'll be fixed when you start your emulator as below

npx react-native run-android