# Unable to resolve module from 'index.js' for custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm kinda new to `react-native` and I'm currently trying to add a `stack-navigator` to my app:

```
// import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

// class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
//   static navigationOptions = {
//     title: 'Welcome',
//   };
//   render() {
//     return (
//       <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
//         <Text>Home Screen</Text>
//       </View>
//     );
//   }
// }

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen}
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
})

const NavigationApp = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeApp', () => NavigationApp)

export default NavigationApp
```

If I uncomment the commented code in the above example, everything works fine, now I'm trying to move the `HomeScreen` component to its own file so I tried this:

**HomeScreen.js**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import HomeScreen from './components'
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen}
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
})

const NavigationApp = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeApp', () => NavigationApp)

export default NavigationApp
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./components` from `index.js`: 

None of these files exist:
  * components(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * components/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at /Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/myuser/git/POC/ReactNativeApp/ReactNativeApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

In the past I've been able to import them the same way as I did, but somehow `react-navigation` is giving me problems with it.

The folder structure that I have is as follows:

```
/
    index.js
    components/
        HomeScreen.js
```

I have seen similar questions but all of them involved third-party components from `react` but not ones made by oneself.

I have tried to `npm start --reset-cache` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122868/2180785)

I'm using these versions if it matters.

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.2
```

How to fix this error?

---

After following @Vencovsky proposed solution (with and without `.js` extension):

```
import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen.js'
```

I get this new error:

```
The component for route 'Home' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Home: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
Home: MyNavigator,
}
```

The way I'm calling this React app is through a Swift bridge in this way:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import React

class ButtonController: UIViewController  {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if let jsBundleLocation = URL(string: "http://X.X.X.X:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios") {
            //The data is used as initialProperties to React Native App.
            let data:NSDictionary = ["onNavigationStateChange": "{handleNavigationChange}",
                                     "uriPrefix":"/app"]; //We can use this parameter to pass the data to the React native App from the Native App.
            //The RCTRootView is a native view used to host React-managed views within the app. Can be used just like any ordinary UIView.
            let rootView = RCTRootView(
                bundleURL: jsBundleLocation,
                moduleName: "ReactNativeApp",
                initialProperties: data as [NSObject : AnyObject],
                launchOptions: nil)
            let viewController = UIViewController()
            viewController.view = rootView
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `import HomeScreen from './components'` should be `import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import it as

```
import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen.js'
```

If you only import it as `'./components'`, it will try to get `./components.js` or `./components/index.js` (and the same but with other extensions), but you don't have any of that.

And if you take a look at the error, it says it tried to get these files but didn't find.

> ```
> None of these files exist:
>   * components(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
>   * components/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> ```

First line with * - Trying to get `./components.js` and other extensions
Second line with * - Trying to get `./components/index.js` and other extensions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the second issue after @Vencovsky answer by changing:

```
export class HomeScreen extends React.Component
```

To:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component
```

After reading this [answer / comment](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3326#issuecomment-396526917) on GitHub.