# i see white screen when run react-native on android emulator

Tags: react-native

i see white screen when run react-native on android emulator .
I am not getting this error when running other projects.
In cmd, the error I get looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PWPz.jpg)

Comment: Try This Solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604603/module-appregistry-is-not-registered-callable-module-calling-runapplication

Comment: I solved the problem as a result of long efforts. The solution mentioned above did not work for me in the first place, but I created the project again and tried this solution and the result was successful.