# Android device version of React-Native project isn't updated, even though simulator is

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have a very strange phenomenon with `React-Native`.  I have been working with the `iOS simulator` mainly but wanted to test my code on my `Android` phone, a `Huawei Nexus 6P`.  Even after removing the old app from the `6P` an older version of my code is run.  Yes, I have updated `index.android.js` to match `index.ios.js` and, to prove it should work, a `Genymotion` simulator of the `6P` runs the correct code.

I even tested a `Kotlin Android` project I'm building and when I ran that on my `6P` any updates to the code were shown as expected.

I will also mention, though it's probably not relevant, I recently (before this problem) had a separate issue that lead me to run `sudo ./gradlew clean` after `CD`ing into the `Android` folder of my project as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014713/1390035).  That didn't fix my issue but I wonder has it somehow 'corrupted' `Gradle` for my project?  Is there a way I can 're-init' or something?

I'm really struggling to understand what could be wrong here, especially since the simulator is updated correctly.  Any help is welcome!

**UPDATE**:

After a helpful tip to clear the cache of the app from `bennygenel` I did the following and reran `react-native run-android` but sadly I still have the same problem:

1. Cleared Cache for the App
2. Cleared the Data
3. Force Stopped the App
4. Uninstalled the App

This is very odd indeed!

Comment: Can you try wiping data of the emulator and then re-installing the app.

Comment: @bennygenel Thanks but the emulator isn't the problem.  The problem is my actual physical `Nexus 6P` :-(

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I got it all wrong. Did you try to clean cache of the app? Also you are not getting any errors while installing right?

Comment: @bennygenel Not yet but that's a good idea.  I'll try now.  There were no errors, just code from some time ago.  I restarted the phone too but that didn't help.

Comment: @bennygenel Good idea but I STILL get the old version of the app.  I really can't explain this!!

Comment: can you try running `watchman watch-del-all && yarn start -- --reset-cache` and then `react-native run-android` on a separate terminal window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156985/discussion-between-dave-chambers-and-bennygenel).