# Android Google Play FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules with React-Native app on Release APK

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, google-play

I'm struggling with my `React Native` app... It used to be deployed correctly with no errors before I updated many of the `librairies` I used in react-native, but now I have errors on `Android & iOS`.

It works fine with react-native run-android or with `Android Studio`, but my release `APK` does not pass Google Play tests.

Here is the Google Play logcat of the errors (partially) :

> 12-12 01:26:15.554: E/ReactNativeJS(13327): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')
>   12-12 01:26:15.556: I/Dpps(892): int DppsFeatureAd3::AdCalcCalibParams(struct DppsAdCfgParam &)():445 calib_a 14, calib_c 0, calib_d 0
>   12-12 01:26:15.558: E/ReactNativeJS(13327): Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
>   12-12 01:26:15.563: E/NetworkScheduler(11214): ignoring stale queue check message
>   12-12 01:26:15.563: E/NetworkScheduler(11214): --------- beginning of crash
>   12-12 01:26:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(13327): FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
>   12-12 01:26:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(13327): Process: com.mdef.mymatchup, PID: 13327

And here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "release": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "installRelease": "cd android && ./gradlew installRelease",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.8.5",
    "d3-interpolate": "1.1.5",
    "es6-symbol": "3.1.1",
    "lodash": "~4.11.2",
    "lodash.range": "3.2.0",
    "module-resolver": "1.0.0",
    "native-base": "2.3.5",
    "native-base-shoutem-theme": "0.1.0",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-communications": "2.2.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "1.6.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase-analytics": "4.0.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.18.1",
    "react-native-sentry": "0.30.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "6.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "5.2.2",
    "redux-thunk": " 2.2.0",
    "striptags": "file:patch/striptags",
    "react-native-fcm-opsone": "file:patch/react-native-fcm"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "metro-bundler": "0.20.2",
    "color-convert": "1.9.1",
    "uglify-js": "github:alexlamsl/UglifyJS2#issue-2449"
  }
}
```

I tried the answers of this issue but it did nothing.
[React-Native: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969858/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)

Did somebody already had the same problem ? It's been 3 days now and I don't know what to do anymore... I need help please !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Native: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969858/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved ! I have fixed my problem by downgrading React-Native from 0.51.0 to 0.49.5, and I have no more crash.