# React native ios release build not working, its says "Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module"

Tags: ios, react-native

Hi getting this error after upgrading react-native from version 0.51.0 to version 0.55.4

```
2018-07-13 15:20:04.876 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Native module cannot be null.
2018-07-13 15:20:04.876332+0530 mobileappb2c[12095:611048] Native module cannot be null.
2018-07-13 15:20:04.879 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.
2018-07-13 15:20:04.879700+0530 mobileappb2c[12095:611052] Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.
2018-07-13 15:20:04.882 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2018-07-13 15:20:04.881977+0530 mobileappb2c[12095:611048] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2018-07-13 15:20:04.882812+0530 mobileappb2c[12095:611052] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null., stack:
t@69:276
```

This issue comes only in release build, Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014713/8898886

Comment: that doesn't work. this is for sure some package which is incompatible with react native, not sure which one.

Comment: You could try then clean the cache and reinstall npm?