# I get a running error with the idex bundle or metro what to do?

Tags: react-native

Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server ('run react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release

Comment: Please tell us about all stuff your issue like code that makes this error, packages, modules, and other good information to other developers can solving your issue.

Comment: This error can happen for many reasons.

Comment: it says unable to resolve module './index'. the Metro is not getting the index and I can t run on my device. I am using adroid studio to relate my phone to the code

Comment: is your metro bundler even running ?

Answer (score 0):

I could have posted this as a comment, but it requires few elaboration hence...

- I tried adding assets folder in projects -> android/app/src/main/
  folder
- checked if my index.js is fine and has all entry fine

> ```
> import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
> import App from "./App";
> import { name as appName } from "./app.json";  
> AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
> ```

- ran this command

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>   index.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res

Now i am able to run the application. All this I tried searching SO, and the reference questions are

1) [stack overflow reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows/44476757#44476757)
2) [Stack overflow reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969858/react-native-module-appregistry-is-not-a-registered-callable-module)