# Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module and Cant find variable: Constants

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to build a simple react native app by using expo android app but I am getting these 2 error log always - Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module and Cant find variable: Constants.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using my mobile hotspot in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer by referring to this link.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014713/11212074)

1. `cd android`
2. `sudo ./gradlew clean`
3. then back to the working directory and run `react-native run-android`

you should restart your npm too after that upgrade.

and

delete the Constant usage in the program.

```js
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants.ConstantName
```

This will cause the Can not find Constants error to disappear.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Using Expo? In which file  import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants.ConstantName  exist.

Comment: You should import from your app.js file.